# How can I bring the Kivy window to the foreground in a Kivy desktop app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

I'm writing a Kivy app for desktop and want to bring the GUI window to the foreground. Is there a nice way to do this using Kivy methods?

(Btw, I already looked at https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.window.html and found nothing. Also, I know how to do this using the WinAPI with ctypes, but the downside is that that would be limited to Windows.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we expose this. It looks like SDL2 provides SDL_RaiseWindow for it, but I guess we don't wrap an api around that right now, although I didn't check.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. The reference to SDL is useful, I didn't know about it and will check it out.